# Complex roots of arbitrary degree of the unity

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, roots-of-unity

For $k$ , $n\in \Bbb Z$, with some abuse of notation $ 1^{1/k}={e^{-j{(2\pi n /k)}}}.$

What is the set of points which are roots of unity of degree $\pi$? (With the same abuse of notation $1^{1/\pi}$).

(1) If one would continue just like before, they may end up with  ${e^{-j{(2n)}}}$, $n\in \Bbb Z$. Is this the complete set of solutions?

(2) $\{z\,|\,z={e^{-j{(2n)}}}, n\in \Bbb Z \}$ and $\{z\,|\, \operatorname{abs}(z)=1 \}\}$ are two different sets, right? (As one is countably infinite other is not.) Then it would be incorrect to say that $\{z\,|\,\operatorname{abs}(z)=1\}$ is the complete set of points which are roots of unity of degree $\pi$.

Thanks, I hope it was not a pointless question and (as far as I checked) not a duplicate.

Comment: 2) I'm not sure why you'd think they'd the the same set.  $(-1)^{\pi} = e^{\pi \ln{-1}} = e^{i (2n + 1)\pi^2} = cos (2n+1)\pi^2 + i \sin(2n+1)\pi^2$ clearly does not equal one.  As $\pi$ is irrational the $k\pi^2 \ne n\pi$ for any rational $k$ or $n$ (other than zero) so $\sin|cos (k\pi^2)$ is never one or zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is the right conceptual generalization.  The set you are looking for is the first set that you indicated, and you're correct that it is not the same thing as $\{x:|x|=1\}$. That set is the entire unit circle, and includes all the roots of unity of any degree. However, your set is actually dense in the unit circle.

A notional comment though: using $j^2=-1$ is **extremely unusual** in mathematics. It's sometimes used in physics or engineering, but virtually never in mathematics.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and regarding the notation your guess was correct ! :)